# Elasticsearch GET / is returning HTML error instead of JSON response

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have recently installed Elasticsearch on RHEL and set the node name in the configuration file. Later, I started the service using the `sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service` The service seems to be running as per the status command

```sh
 sudo systemctl status elasticsearch.service
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-11-25 14:59:13 CET; 2h 37min ago
     Docs: https://www.elastic.co
 Main PID: 6565 (java)
   CGroup: /system.slice/elasticsearch.service
           ├─6565 /usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk/bin/java -Xshare:auto -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=t...
           └─6754 /usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/x-pack-ml/platform/linux-x86_64/bin/controller
Nov 25 14:59:05 hdm18 systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
Nov 25 14:59:13 hdm18 systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
```

But the output of GET is returning an HTML page instead of JSON message

```sh
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/?pretty"
<!-- IE friendly error message walkround.        
     if error message from server is less than   
     512 bytes IE v5+ will use its own error     
     message instead of the one returned by      
     server.                                 --> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta
    enter code here
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you get a chance to go through my answer?? lmk if u need more info

Answer (score 0):

I believe you copied your command from [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/zip-targz.html#_checking_that_elasticsearch_is_running) official link, but if you copy the curl command it will be like `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/?pretty".`

And above will print below correct Output.

```
{
  "name" : "Opster",
  "cluster_name" : "es_710",
  "cluster_uuid" : "SZ-nvW_KSOaudmfB6e0oFg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.10.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "51e9d6f22758d0374a0f3f5c6e8f3a7997850f96",
    "build_date" : "2020-11-09T21:30:33.964949Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: Output of `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/?pretty"` is the same as well. An Elasticsearch java application is listening on port 9200 as shown using the `lsof -i :9200` command. I'm not sure what could be the issue

Comment: @AmarjitSingh can you show the output of `lsof -i :9200` command??

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved by unsetting the http and https proxy by using

```
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
```

Answer (score -1):

You're using Kibana dev console syntax when it looks like you're trying to use curl. check the curl syntax when looking at tutorials.

Probably the easiest for you is to use the dev console in kibana.

Comment: I have not even set up/installed Kibana at all. All I have done is installed ElasticSearch and trying to get an output using the `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/?pretty"` curl command to check if it installed properly.